# Print a string with parsing specifiers

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `"(+ x (division (- x 1)))"` by which can be parsed using `split("\\s*[\\(\\),]+\\s*")`

Output:

```
x
sumup
x
1
```

I need that output according to the paranthesis and spaces(which are the specifiers) in order. I mean I expect that output:

```
(
+
x
(
division 
(
-
x
1
)
)
)
```

How can be it overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to provide your desired output:

```
s.replaceAll("([\\(\\)\\ ])","\n$1\n").replaceAll("\\s*\n+","\n")
```

Comment: the snippet I suggested does still produce the desired output.

Comment: I suppose you are looking for an Array, not a multi-line string - simply add .split("\n") on the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
input.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?<=[-+()\\d])|(?=[-+()\\d])");
```

- first we remove all whitespaces
- then split whats left with zero-width look-ahead and look-behind separators. [Here is a nice article](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/) on how look-ahead look-behind works.